# Sort json output in ansible or receive the newest file

Tags: ansible

I want to get the newest file from the directory but the problem is that the response is not sorted so my "newest" file is the old one due to using json_query.

In my directory, I have a couple of files

```
test123.zip => created 01.01.2020
test1234.zip => created 07.01.2020
tested12345.zip => created 04.02.2020
```

The output from ansible is

```
test1234.zip
test12345.zip
test123.zip
```

So the `test123.zip` is the last. I can't use a specific name because the names are different. I need to obtain the newest file by date.

In my playbook I have:

```
tasks:
      - name: Find the newest zip file
        win_find:
          paths: \\localhost\zipfiles\
          get_checksum: no
        register: zipfile_the_newest
      - debug:
          msg: "{{ zipfile_the_newest | json_query('files[].filename') | last }}"
```

The output is:

```
test123.zip
```

And my question is how to get the newest file by date or how to sort the output that the newest file will be on the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `win_find:` module [documentation says](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/win_find_module.html#return-files/creationtime) that it returns `creationtime` as an attribute of every file, so you will want to sort by that value